# My JPA Repository request is returning with cache without me enabling it in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like a help, because I am performing 3 queries in a sequential way, however Spring and JPA is applying a Cache on different objects

The child object Establishment is returning the same in memory, but in each object "food, medication and accessories" I have to make different changes to that child object, but when I change it, it seems that the Establishment comes as a reference, that is, I change it in a and replicate in others.

```
Establishment  obj = establishmentService.findById(id);

List<EstablishmentProduct> food        = repo.findByEstablishmentAndProductSegment(obj, SegmentEnum.FOOD.getCod());
List<EstablishmentProduct> medication  = repo.findByEstablishmentAndProductSegment(obj, SegmentEnum.MEDICATION.getCod());
List<EstablishmentProduct> accessories = repo.findByEstablishmentAndProductSegment(obj, SegmentEnum.ACCESSORIES.getCod());
```

My Entity

```
@Entity
public class EstablishmentProduct implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String  description;
    private Integer status;
    private Integer quantity;
    private Double  value;
    private Integer productSegment;
    private boolean deleted = false;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "establishment_id")
    private Establishment establishment;
```

```
@Repository
public interface EstablishmentProductRepository extends JpaRepository<EstablishmentProduct, Integer> {
    
    List<EstablishmentProduct> findByEstablishmentAndProductSegment(Establishment establishment, Integer productSegment);
```

Guys, as much as the query is being made by Entity, already test by the establishment ID and return the same pointer of the child class of Entity Establishment

**Establishment obj = establishmentService.findById (id);**

It seems to me that Spring and JPA is applying a cache that I didn't request, I would like that for each **findByEstablishmentAndProductSegment** ne it would return with new child objects, without cache.

I have already disabled caching in all ways and nothing worked.

I know that the Establishment object does not change, but the Product object does, but as I mentioned, I need to make changes to the establishment for each segment returned

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the effect of the 1st level cache of JPA which can't disabled. But you may either evict some or all entities form the `EntityManager` or start a new session, which would start with an empty cache.

Comment: yes, but could you provide an example with spring boot?  My settings are all from the application.properties, thank you